How can i convert 12-hours to 24-hours in vue.js?
I am new to vue.js. I wrote this code:
<li class="list-inline-item me-3">
              <h5
                    class="font-size-14"
                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-placement="top"
                    title="From"
                  >
                  <label>Start time</label>
                  <br />
                  <i class="bx bx-time me-1 text-muted">
                    <b-form-input class="no-border" :value="object.start_time.slice(0,5)" :disabled="!object.can_change" @input="object.start_time = $event"
                    format="HH:mm" value-type="format" type="time" placeholder="HH:mm"></b-form-input>
                  </i></h5>
            </li>

This code show the time with hours and minutes. The problem is that hours are 12 hours with am and pm but I want 24 hours. How can I do this?

if you know the HH is PM can't you just add 12 to the value to show in 24h format?

What's the format of the time you're receiving? Date-fns can manage that part and the other way around with the format function, check the a..aa and HH parts.

I'm guessing object.start_time.slice(0,5) is the HH:mm part of a 12h formatted time like 12:00 am. Ideally, you would store a parsed datetime object or numeric timestamp in that property instead and format it where you need it, but if you don't have control over the data, you could split the string and do the math yourself, or have it parsed and formatted by a function:
const to24h = (time12h: string) =>
  new Date('1970 ' + time12h).toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false, timeStyle: 'short' })

< ... :value="to24h(object.start_time)" ... />


Please add your time source for further context. 
Because I dont know how the time data looks I'll assume that you get it as a string based on your Issue description. 
If you want to display a timepicker with bootstrap vue, use the form-timepicker. 
There you can configure the hour cycle.
If it is a string that you just want to transform, you can create a function / pipe to transform the value like this.
// e.g. timeString = '9 pm'
formatToHH(timeString: string): number | undefined {
    const split = timeString.split(' ');

    if (split.length <= 1) {
        return;
    }

    if (split[1] === 'am') {
        return Number(split[0]);
    }

    if (split[1] === 'pm') {
        return Number(split[0]) * 2;
    }

    return;
}


I did it. I put it in html but the hours are null

@Mike you did what? Using the timepicker or format function? How did you implement it? Where did you implement it?
It is very hard to help you with inaccurate information,

You can use the Date object:
function convertTo24Hour() {
    let date = new Date();

    return date.toLocaleTimeString(
        'en-US',
        { hour12: false },
    );
}

